# The Integration Services component is not installed or you do not have permission to use it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

Since I am using SMO to copy data from one database to another. I have used my own DB helper class. I am getting exception when i transfer data.

**The Integration Services component is not installed or you do not have permission to use it.**

My code is as follows:

```
public class DBHelper
{
    #region Private Variables
    private static string sourceSQLServer;
    private static string destinationSQLServer;
    private static string sourceDatabase;
    private static string destinationDatabase;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// SourceSQLServer Holds Instance Name of Source SQL Server Database Name
    /// </summary>
    public static string SourceSQLServer
    {
        get { return DBHelper.sourceSQLServer; }
        set { DBHelper.sourceSQLServer = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DestinationSQLServer Holds Instance Name of Destination SQL Server Database Name
    /// </summary>
    public static string DestinationSQLServer
    {
        get { return DBHelper.destinationSQLServer; }
        set { DBHelper.destinationSQLServer = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SourceDatabase Holds Source Database 
    /// </summary>
    public static string SourceDatabase
    {
        get { return DBHelper.sourceDatabase; }
        set { DBHelper.sourceDatabase = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DestinationDatabase Holds Destination Database Name
    /// </summary>
    public static string DestinationDatabase
    {
        get { return DBHelper.destinationDatabase; }
        set { DBHelper.destinationDatabase = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Static Methods
    /// <summary>
    ///  CopyDatabase Copies Database 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="CopyData">True if Want to Copy Data otherwise False</param>
    public static void CopyDatabase(bool bCopyData)
    {
        //Set Source SQL Server Instance Information
        Server server = new Server(DBHelper.SourceSQLServer);

        //Set Source Database Name [Database to Copy]
        Database database = server.Databases[DBHelper.SourceDatabase];

        //Set Transfer Class Source Database
        Transfer transfer = new Transfer(database);

        //Yes I want to Copy All the Database Objects
        transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;

        //In case if the Destination Database / Objects Exists Drop them First
        transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;

        //Copy Database Schema
        transfer.CopySchema = true;

        //Copy Database Data Get Value from bCopyData Parameter
        transfer.CopyData = bCopyData;

        //Set Destination SQL Server Instance Name
        transfer.DestinationServer = DBHelper.DestinationSQLServer;

        //Create The Database in Destination Server
        transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = true;

        //Set Destination Database Name
        Database ddatabase = new Database(server, DBHelper.DestinationDatabase);

        //Create Empty Database at Destination
        ddatabase.Create();

        //Set Destination Database Name
        transfer.DestinationDatabase = DBHelper.DestinationDatabase;

        //Include If Not Exists Clause in the Script
        transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;

        //Start Transfer
        transfer.TransferData();

        //Release Server variable
        server = null;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and on Main function I am calling this

```
DBHelper.SourceSQLServer = @"DESKTOP-PCEOPRM\SQLEXPRESS";

//Set Your Database Name Here (To Be Copied or Scripted)
DBHelper.SourceDatabase = "MetisEmptyDB";

////Set Destination SQL Server Name Here
DBHelper.DestinationSQLServer = @"DESKTOP-PCEOPRM\SQLEXPRESS";

//Set New Database Name Here 
DBHelper.DestinationDatabase = "NewDb";

//Set True if you want to copy Data
//Set False if you want to copy Only Schema
DBHelper.CopyDatabase(true);
Console.WriteLine("Scripting Finished");
```

Thanks in advance. If you find any other alternate of making a new db from existing one in C# than you can please share the code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in the error. You are trying to use code for SQL Server Integration Services but that is not included in SQL Server Express.

Also these things are a lot easier using T-SQL. You can easily create new empty databases and script the objects too. Or backup and restore the database.

I should not post the code here in stackoverflow as it will be better asked at dba.stackexchange.com

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012   
 TO DISK = 'C:\SQLServerBackups\AdvWorksData.bak' 
 WITH FORMAT;
```

and to restore on the other server

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
  FROM DISK = 'C:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak';
```

Make sure that you understand what you are doing in SQL before you try and do it via C#. You would learn more about SQL if you did all of the sql manually using SQLCMD as recommended in previous questions.

Comment: i have used that code too here at the question, but instead of helping people are doing down vote. I dont't know why people do so with a beginner. If you can help please see this question. @Mike

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019461/run-a-script-on-existing-database-from-sql-file-in-c-sharp/39019576

Comment: I have added the simplest sql example for backing up and restoring a database. Ensure that this works in SQL before you try and run it from c#

Comment: Thank you @Mike, it was simplest. I read three of the methods, one was SMO, second was the one you proposed me and the third was the process method with SQLcmd. Hope this one would work!

Answer (score 1):

For me this error went away when I changed my dependency from SQL Server 2008 Express to SQL Server 2012 Express.

I referenced the assemblies in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies
```

Not

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies
```

If you are able to change the dependency then it works.